# Can't find VS2015 TeamFoundationServerExt on nuget

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015

I've referenced the latest Microsoft Team Foundation nuget packages found at https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/get-started/client-libraries/dotnet but I cannot find a reference anywhere for TeamFoundationServerExt. Does anybody know if these have been moved to a nuget package too? If not where can I reference from (I was hoping not to use direct paths to Visual Studio 2015)?

Comment: Which class are you looking for exactly? That Assembly name you mention has never been part of the official client object model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for:

> https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/

```
 PM> Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient
```

I'm not sure which Assembly you're looking for, Microsoft has never shipped a TeamFoundationServerExt assembly, all the functionality you need is broken into one of the at least 20 assemblies added to your project when referencing this package.

There is a class TeamfoundationServerExt, which is part of the assembly `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation`, that one is part of the Visual Studio SDK and/or full Visual Studio installation and is not available as a redistributable Nuget package as far as I am aware of.

Comment: Yes that class - but the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TeamFoundation is not in the GAC any more, so is the only way to access it to go direct?

Comment: Correct. Microsoft has made most of Visual Studio GAC-less with 2015.

Comment: Fair enough - but why not provide nuget packages for all the missing assemblies then? Pointing to a hard coded folder in references is akin to dll-hell... Boo Microsoft. Is there maybe an official place this can be discussed with them?

Comment: Those assemblies are usable stand-alone for tools communicating with Visual Studio Online or TFS. Integrating into Visual Studio itself is another matter and doesn't come with a free redistributable license.

Comment: You could do as I did, look up the location from the registry and reference it that way. Saves a lot of trouble: https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/blob/master/References/TfsReferences.target

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92972/discussion-between-mladen-mihajlovic-and-jessehouwing).

Answer (score 0):

I am using the nuget package Microsoft.TeamFoundation.ObjectModel  I does have the down side of only being for .net 4.5